# How to render a Commerce pane programmatically?

Tags: 7, theming, commerce

I've the following code:

```
$panes = commerce_checkout_panes();
$payment_pane = $panes['commerce_payment'];
```

which loads one of Commerce pane which contains the array like:

```
array (size=15)
  'title' => string 'Payment' (length=7)
  'page' => string 'review' (length=6)
  'file' => string 'includes/commerce_payment.checkout_pane.inc' (length=43)
  'base' => string 'commerce_payment_pane' (length=21)
...
```

How do I render that pane programmatically?

This is part of `commerce_checkout_form_review` form (which is normally present at `/checkout/%/review`), but I need to render only payment part (checkboxes) but in different place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Panes are forms. Run them through `drupal_get_form` but you'll need to pass in some extra options:

```
require_once drupal_get_path('module', $payment_pane['module']) . '/' . $payment_pane['file'];
$order = commerce_order_load($order_id);
$payment_form = drupal_get_form($payment_pane['callbacks']['checkout_form'], $payment_pane, $order);
$output = drupal_render($payment_form);
```

Comment: This gets me all the pane elements but in raw format.. Any idea how I can get the themes results ?